# Is it possible to cache XML documents in Saxon to avoid re-parsing and re-indexing?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am currently assessing whether XSLT3 with Saxon could be useful for our purposes. Please hear me out.

We are developing a REST API which provides credentials given an input request XML. Basically, there are 3 files in play:

- `site.xml`:

  - This file holds the data representing the complete organisation: users, roles, credentials, settings, ...
  - It could easily contain 10.000 lines.
  - It could be considered as static/immutable.
  - You could compare it as XML representation of a database, so to say.
- `request.xml`:

  - This file holds the request as provided to the REST API.
  - It is rather small, usually around 10 to 50 lines.
  - It is different for each request.
- `request.xslt`:

  - This file holds the stylesheet to convert the given `request.xml` to an output XML.
  - It loads `site.xml` via the XSLT `document()` function, as it needs that data to fulfill the request.

The problem here is that loading `site.xml` in `request.xslt` takes a long time. In addition, for each request, indexes as introduced by the XSLT `<xsl:key .../>` directive must be rebuilt. This adds up.

So it would make sense to somehow cache `site.xml`, to avoid having to parse and index that file for every request.

It's important to note that multiple API requests can happen concurrently, thus it should be safe to share this cached `site.xml` between several ongoing XSLT transformations.

Is this possible with Saxon (Java)? How would that work?

**Update 1**

After some additional reflecting, I realize that maybe I should not attempt to just cache the `site.xml` XML file, but the `request.xslt` instead? This assumes that `site.xml`, which is loaded in `request.xslt` via `document()`, is part of that cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you show/tell us which API you use to run XSLT with Saxon.

As for caching the XSLT, with JAXP I think you can do that with a `Templates` created with `newTemplates` from the `TransformerFactoryImpl` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/jaxp-transformation.html), each time you want to run the XSLT you will to create a `Transformer` with `newTransformer()`.

With the s9api API you can compile once to get an `XsltExecutable` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltExecutable.html) that "is immutable, and therefore thread-safe", you then have to us `load()` or `load30()` to create an `XsltTransformer` or `Xslt30Transformer` each time you need to run the code.

As for sharing a document, see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/preloading.html:

> An option is available (Feature.PRE_EVALUATE_DOC_FUNCTION) to indicate
>   that calls to the doc() or document() functions with constant string
>   arguments should be evaluated when a query or stylesheet is compiled,
>   rather than at run-time. This option is intended for use when a
>   reference or lookup document is used by all queries and
>   transformations

The section on that configuration option, however, states:

> In XSLT 3.0 a better way of having external documents pre-loaded at
>   stylesheet compile time is to use the new facility of static global
>   variables.

So in that case you could declare

```
<xsl:variable name="site-doc" static="yes" select="doc('site.xml')"/>
```

You will need to wait on Michael Kay's response as to whether that suffices to share the document.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your insights, these are very useful. I did not yet write any useful code, so that's why I did not show any. I am definitely going to try out the `Xslt30Transformer` with the `PRE_EVALUATE_DOC_FUNCTION` feature enabled. That sounds exactly what I need here.

Comment: Both answers are great and contain much more knowledge than I could have hoped for. I randomly picked one as the accepted answer, but I would have loved to accept both. Thank you kindly.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that the PRE_EVALUATE_DOC_FUNCTION is indiscriminate: if you have both `doc('site.xml')` and doc('request.xml')` in your stylesheet, then it will apply to both.

Comment: Right! Thank you for the heads-up. My idea was to import the `site.xml` via `doc()` (while relying on the caching feature from `Feature.PRE_EVALUATE_DOC_FUNCTION`) and provide `request.xml` to the `Xslt30Transformer.transform()` function, as explained on http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is certainly possible, but the best way of doing it depends a little on the circumstances, e.g. what happens when site.xml changes.

I would be inclined to create a single s9api Processor at application startup, and immediately (that is, during application initialization) load site.xml into an `XdmNode` using `Processor.DocumentBuilder.build()`; this can then be passed as a parameter value (an `<xsl:param>`) into each transformation that uses it. Or if you prefer to access it using `document()`, you could register a `URIResolver` that responds to the `document()` call by returning the relevant `XdmNode`.

As for indexing and the `key()` function, so long as the `xsl:key` definition is "sharable", then if two transformations based on the same compiled stylesheet (s9api `XsltExecutable`) access the same document, the index will not be rebuilt. An `xsl:key` definition is shareable if its `match` and `use` attributes do not depend on anything that can vary from one transformation to another, such as the content of global variables or parameters.

Saxon's native tree implementations (unlike the DOM) are thread-safe: if you build a document once, you can access it in multiple threads. The building of indexes to support the key() function is synchronized so concurrent transformations will not interfere with each other.

Martin's suggestion of allowing compile-time evaluation of the document() call would also work. You could also put the document into a global variable defined with static="yes". This doesn't play well, however, with exporting compiled stylesheets into persistent files: there are some restrictions that apply when exporting a stylesheet that contains node-valued static variables.

Comment: Thank your Michael for your insights, these are very useful. Alongside Martin's suggestion, I will definitely try out to parse `site.xml` into an `XdmNode` and pass that to the transformation. That looks very promising and is probably what I was looking after. It's also good to hear that thread-safety is covered here.

Comment: Both answers are great and contain much more knowledge than I could have hoped for. I randomly picked one as the accepted answer, but I would have loved to accept both. Thank you kindly.